# Check on change if any other select tag with same option class exists via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code for two dropdown selectors:

```
<select class="sel1">
    <option class="c21" selected></option>
    <option class="c20"></option>
</select>

<select class="sel2">
    <option class="c21" selected></option>
    <option class="c22"></option>
</select>
```

How can I check if two selected options in different `<select>` tags have the same class?

```
$('.sel1').change(fucntion(){
    var op1class = $('.sel1 option:selected').attr("class");
    // How can I check if any other selected <select> tag has the same option class?
});
```

Comment: My guess is that you're using the class to inform the user about some kind of underlying logic. I would recommend you program against your logic, not the state of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `$` in `('.sel1 option:selected').attr("class");`

```
$('.sel1').change(function(){
  var op1class = $('.sel1 option:selected').attr("class");
  var op2class = $('.sel2 option:selected').attr("class");
  if(op1class == op2class ){
    //you code
  }
  alert(op1class);
  alert(op2class);
});
```

**upDated**

```
$('.sel1').change(function(){
  var op1class = $('select option:selected').attr("class");
  var arr = $('select option:selected').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("class");
  }).get()
  //var op2class = $('.sel2 option:selected').attr("class");
  //if(op1class == op2class ){
    //you code
  //}
  alert(arr);
  //alert(op2class);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g52bw42p/)**

Comment: Problem is i dont have only two selectors, i can have more than two dropdown selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all selected options via `$('option:selected')`. Then simply iterate through them and see if it contains the class of your reference option*. Be aware that the option from "sel1" is also part of the array, so you need to filter this element, i.e. by reading it's parent's class.

*See @Ana Vinatoru's comment on how to do that properly.

Comment: Instead of comparing classes, (s)he could use jQuery's hasClass function: https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/  - just to account for the case when they have more than one class set